# Continuous operator input not working propertly

Tags: javascript, arrays, calculator

I'm working on a calculator, and although it's missing some functions, my current issue is that it's not handling continuous operations correctly. I ran a test on a regular calculator with the following operation: 100+100+10+5-100. The correct result is 115, but in my calculator, it's giving 105. I suspect the error lies in the getResult() function, but I've been stuck on this problem for 2 days without finding a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const displayElement = document.getElementById("display"),
  buttonElements = document.querySelectorAll("button[meta-operator]");

let result;
let simbol;
let storage = [];
let clickCounter = 0;

const clean = () => {
  buttonElements.forEach((button) => {
    if (button.classList.contains("is-active")) button.classList.remove("is-active");
  });

  storage.splice(0, storage.length);
  displayElement.classList.remove("is-active");
  clickCounter = 0;
  displayElement.value = "";
};

const ac = () => {
  clean();
  displayElement.value = 0;
};

const getResult = () => {
  switch (simbol) {
    case "+":
      result = storage[storage.length - 1] + Number(displayElement.value);
      break;

    case "-":
      result = storage[storage.length - 1] - Number(displayElement.value);
      break;

    case "*":
      result = storage[storage.length - 1] * Number(displayElement.value);
      break;

    case "/":
      result = storage[storage.length - 1] / Number(displayElement.value);
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  return result;
};

const operation = () => {
  getResult();

  buttonElements.forEach((button) => {
    if (button.classList.contains("is-active")) button.classList.remove("is-active");
  });

  storage.push(result);

  displayElement.value = result;

  storage.splice(0, storage.length - 1);

  displayElement.classList.add("is-active");

  clickCounter = 0;
};

const continueOperation = (e) => {
  getResult();

  storage.push(result);

  displayElement.value = result;

  storage.splice(0, storage.length - 2);
};

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.target.hasAttribute("meta-number")) {
    if (displayElement.value == 0 || clickCounter >= 2) displayElement.value = "";

    if (clickCounter >= 2) clickCounter--;

    if (storage.length == 1 && displayElement.classList.contains("is-active")) clean();

    displayElement.value += Number(e.target.id);

    buttonElements.forEach((button) => {
      if (button.classList.contains("is-active")) button.classList.remove("is-active");
    });
  }

  if (e.target.hasAttribute(`meta-operator`)) {
    clickCounter++;

    if (clickCounter >= 2 && !e.target.classList.contains("is-active")) {
      buttonElements.forEach((button) => {
        if (button.classList.contains("is-active")) button.classList.remove("is-active");
      });

      e.target.classList.add("is-active");

      simbol = e.target.id;
    }

    if (clickCounter >= 2) {
      continueOperation(e);
      return;
    }

    e.target.classList.add("is-active");

    buttonElements.forEach((button) => {
      if (button.classList.contains("is-active")) {
        simbol = button.id;
      }
    });

    storage.push(Number(displayElement.value));
    displayElement.value = 0;
  }

  if (e.target.hasAttribute("meta-equal")) {
    operation();
  }

  if (e.target.hasAttribute("meta-ac")) {
    ac();
  }
});
```

This is the complete code I have so far. I apologize if it's hard to read or if there are any additional errors; I welcome any advice or suggestions. I'm still learning.

I've tried so many things that I've lost count; none of them have yielded results.

I'm not sure if my code is the most optimal for a calculator. I've been looking at other projects on GitHub, and their codes are completely different from mine. I don't know if the issue is that my code simply needs to be rewritten to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, when you click on an operator, you immediately execute the  operator from the *current* click instead of the *previous* one. Ie if you do `100 + 20 + 30` and then click on `-` you don't do an addition of 30 (the previous operation) but a substraction (ie the current operation). Because with clicking on an operator you are assigning the `simbol` variable and you do the calculations only after that ...

A simple fix for that would be in case of a `continueOperation` to assign the `simbol` only *after* you executed the calculations ...

```
if (e.target.hasAttribute(`meta-operator`)) {
  clickCounter++;

  if (clickCounter >= 2 && !e.target.classList.contains("is-active")) {
    buttonElements.forEach((button) => {
      if (button.classList.contains("is-active")) button.classList.remove("is-active");
    });

    e.target.classList.add("is-active");
    // REMOVE THE ASSIGNMENT FROM HERE
    // simbol = e.target.id; 
  }

  if (clickCounter >= 2) {
    continueOperation(e);
    // ADD THE ASSIGNMENT HERE
    simbol = e.target.id; 
    return;
  }

  e.target.classList.add("is-active");

  buttonElements.forEach((button) => {
    if (button.classList.contains("is-active")) {
      simbol = button.id;
    }
  });

  storage.push(Number(displayElement.value));
  displayElement.value = 0;
}
```

This will at least fix the calculations for `+` and `-` ...

But your approach has an additional problem: It's not following the precedence rules for `*` and `/`. Ie if you do something like `10 + 3 * 4` it actually calculates `(10 + 3) * 4` which gives `52` instead of `10 + (3 * 4)` which is `22`. But that's not an easy fix ...

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, I'm working on it

Comment: @WilmerMedina  If that answer helped you, please don't hesistate to upvote and/or accept it ...